# Is there a way to cast a void pointer to a pointer to "something" of a specific size?

Tags: c, pointers, generics, casting, void-pointers

I'm only a beginner when it comes to C, so this might be a bad question.

I've been trying to implement some generic types as an exercise, and so far I've had to resort to using an enum with a bunch of case labels in order to set/retrieve data. Something vaguely like this:

```c
typedef enum ElementType {
    FOO_U8,
    FOO_U16,
    // ...
} ElementType;

void foo_insert(Foo* foo, void* elem) 
{
    switch (foo->elem_type) {
        case FOO_U8:
            *(uint8_t*)foo->data = *(uint8_t*)elem;
            break;
        case FOO_U16:
            *(uint16_t*)foo->data = *(uint16_t*)elem;
            // ...
}
```

I have these switch statements all over the place, *including* in a function that returns the size of the element in bytes.

Given that *all* data is technically just bytes, it'd be nice if instead of casting a `void*` to a *specific* `type*` I could just manually tell it how many bytes to dereference. Something like `*(dynamic_type(8)*)elem`.

Is this possible?

Comment: That's just not possible. For example, how would you differ between different types with the same size? Like `long long` and `double` (both 8 bytes), or even `unsigned int` and `int`?

Comment: OTOH, one can `memcpy` a specific size disregarding the type.

Comment: On another note, unless you're doing something like binary serialization (but then you need to remember endianness issues) what you're doing is usually an anti-pattern and a possible sign of a bad design.

Comment: Please add a relevant example of usage of foo_insert() function